# libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: gtk4

I am trying to get the example from the [docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.DrawingArea.html) working but I keep on getting this error

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

I installed the packages

```
sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev 
sudo apt-get install libgtk-4-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

I also updated the system but nothing seems to fix this issue

Comment: The error message indicates that the system is unable to authenticate the user. This can be caused by a number of factors, including incorrect permissions on the files required for authentication or a misconfigured system. Try checking the permissions on the files required for authentication and ensure that the system is properly configured.

Comment: @LuckyOwl i tried running the executable with `sudo` before doing and config changes and got this error 
`Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified`